# pandas.merge with coinciding column names

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Consider the following data frames:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': list('fghij'), 'A': ['A' + str(i) for i in range(5)]})
    A id
0  A0  f
1  A1  g
2  A2  h
3  A3  i
4  A4  j
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': list('fg'), 'B': ['B' + str(i) for i in range(2)]})
    B id
0  B0  f
1  B1  g
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'id': list('ij'), 'B': ['B' + str(i) for i in range(3, 5)]})
    B id
0  B3  i
1  B4  j
```

I want to merge them to get

```
    A id    B
0  A0  f   B0
1  A1  g   B1
2  A2  h  NaN
3  A3  i   B3
4  A4  j   B4
```

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30512931/8472781) I tried

```
final = reduce(lambda l, r: pd.merge(l, r, how='outer', on='id'), [df1, df2, df3])
```

but unfortunately it yields

```
    A id  B_x  B_y
0  A0  f   B0  NaN
1  A1  g   B1  NaN
2  A2  h  NaN  NaN
3  A3  i  NaN   B3
4  A4  j  NaN   B4
```

Additionally, I checked out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45575165/how-to-merge-overlapping-columns) but I can't adapt the solution to my problem. Also, I didn't find any options in the [docs for pandas.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) to make this happen.

In my real world problem the list of data frames might be much longer and the size of the data frames might be much larger.

Is there any "pythonic" way to do this directly and without "postprocessing"? It would be perfect to have a solution that raises an exception if column B of df2 and df3 would overlap (so if there might be multiple candidates for some value in column B of the final data frame).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `pd.concat` + `groupby`?

```
pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=0).groupby('id').first().reset_index()

  id   A    B
0  f  A0   B0
1  g  A1   B1
2  h  A2  NaN
3  i  A3   B3
4  j  A4   B4
```

Comment: This solution also works for `df3 = pd.DataFrame({'id': list('ijk'), 'B': ['B' + str(i) for i in range(3, 6)]})` (a case I forgot in my minimal example). Thanks!